# notify.js doesn't show notification when error

Tags: javascript, ajax, error-handling, notifications

why don't I get any error notification even if an error message exists in the response object?

```
 $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {

        if ( "error_message" in response ) {
            console.log(response);
            $.notify("Rendez-vous existant", "error");
        }
        else {
            $.notify("Rendez-vous ajouté", {"status":"success"});
        }


        $('.modal.in').modal('hide')
        table.destroy();
        $('#datatable4 tbody').empty(); // empty in case the columns change
        getAppointment()
    });
```

this is what I get in the console log:

```
  error_message"Rendez-vous existant, veuillez choisir une autre date"
```

Answer (score 0):

`"error_message" in response` is not correct JavaScript syntax. Assuming the `error_message` property either does not exist in the response, or is some value other `0, null, false, undefined`, then `response.error_message` will be evaluated as `true`.

Change your condition to read:

```
if (response.error_message) {
    console.log(response);
    $.notify("Rendez-vous existant", "error");
}
```

Comment: it still doesn't notify me with anything, it's just stuck with 403 Forbidden POST with a response with the same object of the error msg

Comment: @Glamarouane What is the result of `console.log(response)` outside of the `if` statement?

Comment: And you're getting the `console.log` inside the `if(){}` to fire?

Comment: If the condition evaluates to true then my only guess is that you're using `$.notify` incorrectly